# Xamarin forms transparent navigation bar with visible back button

Tags: xamarin, navigationbar

I am currently trying to make a navigation page in a Xamarin Forms cross platform application that has a transparent/invisible navigation bar, but still shows a back button? Does Xamarin forms support any quick and easy way to do this?

Comment: You may refer to this https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/1698

Comment: A blog post was written on this ... https://xamgirl.com/transparent-navigation-bar-in-xamarin-forms/

Answer (score 0):

You could do either of these two:

- Option 1 : Making a Custom renderer that will customize your nav bar
- Option 2 : Hiding your navigation bar and then make your own
  navigation bar either stacklayout,grid, etc.

then set your navigation bar to transparent and the back button with a color

Answer (score -1):

If you are using Navigation Page as your navigation paradigm, you can use:

```
NavigationPage.SetHasBackButton(this, false);
```

This will remove the back button from the navigation bar.